# autoload zf3 module without terminal command

Tags: module, autoload, autoloader, zend-framework3, composer-php

I am using ZendFramwork3, i'm new in this so don't know how to autoload the module after creation without terminal command.

I am creating module with programme just by taking module name from the user the following things will be done : 
  - Module structure for new module with namespace and controller & view files will be placed under module folder
  - ModuleName is initialised in modules.config.php in config folder
  - Also entry in composer.json in autoload --> psr-4 initialisation done

After that i have to manually run the command "composer dump-autoload" to perfectly work my module but i don't want to do that manually rather i want solution for that to run it programmatically.

Thank you for the solution in advance.

Comment: You don't have to use composer. Maybe you can write your own autoloader. But what's wrong with terminal command?

Comment: I want to do that automatically using code so developer just have to enter the name of the Module and all procedure will be done automatically with auto loading also.
Please help me out in that, Thank you so much for your consideration @Mehmet SÖĞÜNMEZ.

Comment: I'd write a few lines code to do that. Developer have to write module's name to my program so i can update config file and trigger composer to dump new psr-4 schema. Also there's composer scripts but i'm sure you have to trigger them via terminal again. You might want to check it: https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/scripts.md